# Creating and printing a simple table

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, printing

I'm building a simple Bingo generator able to genrate Bingo Cards containing words or pictures.

All that is pretty simple but I can't figure out how to print the generated cards. I tought i't would be simple, but I just cannot find that simple way.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, i just need to print fixed size table containing from a list of Words or pictures. with One table per page.

I built my application in WinForm, but I'm thinking about doing it with WPF so I'm looking for solutions in any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One control I really like in WPF and which could fit your task as well is the FlowDocumentControl.

It has a built in Table-structure which should cover a bingo like display.
Have a look at that [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133.aspx) on how to create a table like structure in a FlowDocument.

This [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/printing-in-wpf/) shows how to print the FlowDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WPF Grid element with the number of columns and rows you need. You can put anything you want in each cell, including another grid or a stack panel holding your words/pictures. Look into Grid, Grid.ColumnDefinitions, Grid.RowDefinitions to define the grid, and Grid.Column/Grid.Row to position the contents.